# How can I parse a URL using JSON in Python?

Tags: json, python-2.7

I have a URL on my Raspberry Pi device server. How can I parse it?

I have used the urllib2 module to get the contents of the URL from server.
I want to use JSON for parsing the url.

Comment: Do you mean "I've retrieved a JSON file from a certain url. How do I parse JSON in Python?"

Comment: You can use the standard json library. Here is the link to the documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: I have a getcommands.txt file on my raspberrypi which is encoded by json script i want to get it using json parsing in python script

Answer (score -1):

so if i understad properly , you have a json file with a URL that you want to pass to your python module

used this a while back

```
import json

with open('yourjasonfilewithurl.jason') as json_data_file:
  data = json.load(json_data_file)
```

The use the data function like this, the below is dependant on the number of elements you have set up in your json config file

```
myurl = (data["details"][0]["url"])
```

hope this helps